# Understanding JavaScript evaluation

Tags: javascript

I am fixing some code and trying to understand a certain evaluation that is happening. There was a little snippet written where 2 evaluations should happen like so :

```js
const active = true;
const isPerson = true;
const person1Time = null;
const person2Time = null;

// this one is not working as intended
const original = !active && isPerson ? !person1Time : !person2Time;

console.log("original", original);

// fixed when second evaluation is wrapped in parens
const fix = !active && (isPerson ? !person1Time : !person2Time);

console.log("fixed", fix);
```

I was able to fix the code to the desired result by wrapping the ternary evaluation in parentheses. What I am wondering is - why it works like this? The `!active` evaluates to false, and the ternary evaluates to true, and a `console.log(true && false)`, this evaluates to false. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something here.

Comment: [The boolean AND has a higher operator precedence than the conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: It is evaluated as `(!active && isPerson) ? !person1Time : !person2Time`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the [operator precedence rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

- Binary AND (`x && y`) is priority 6.
- Ternary (`x ? y : z`) is priority 4.
- Unary NOT (`!x`) is priority 17.

Therfore, the NOT operator is evaluated first, then the binary AND, and lastly the ternary operator.

Comment: so based on what you're saying, the parenthases should look like this? `((!active) && isPerson) ? (!person1Time) : (!person2Time);`

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  All of the NOT expressions will be evaluated first, followed by the AND, and finally the ternary.

Answer (score 4):

Boolean operators take precedence over ternary operators. In other words, this:

`!active && isPerson ? !person1Time : !person2Time;`

is equivalent to this:

`(!active && isPerson) ? !person1Time : !person2Time;`

Therefore, you obtain a different result.

Answer (score 0):

The `original` is evaluating the entire conditional expression on the left side of the ternary operator: `!active && isPerson`. **Then** based on the result of that expression - `true` or `false` - it evaluates the correct result.